# mantener la modificación de un setinterval con una cookie o un localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Buenas!!

Tengo una página que hace un barrido automático de ratón a una velocidad nada más acceder a esta página pero además tengo un botón para aumentar esta velocidad todo esto por medio de setintervals:

Velocidad por defecto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  t = setInterval(clickbutton, 3000);
}
```

Botón que aumenta la velocidad:

```
function aumentar() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setInterval(clickbutton, 100);
}
```

Lo que no consigo hacer es que una vez pulsado el botón que aumenta la velocidad se mantenga al acceder a otros sitios de la web o al refrescar la página. He leído que esto se podría hacer mediante cookies o con un localstorage pero al ser un valor numérico no consigo hacerlo, ya que todo lo que leo es por medio de strings.

Alguien sabría cómo hacerlo?? Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres usar local storage, ten en cuenta que los valores se almancena como cadena de texto por lo que puede ser necesario parsearlos.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // valor por defecto 3000
  var duracion = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('duracion') || '3000');
  t = setInterval(clickbutton, duracion);
}
```

Botón que aumenta la velocidad:

```
function aumentar() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setInterval(clickbutton, 100);
  localStorage.setItem('duracion', '100')
}
```

Si quieres resetear la duracion puedes usar `removeItem`

```
localStorage.removeItem('duracion')
```

Comment: muchiiiiiisimaassss gracias!! funcionó a la perfección!!!